# Why are '[' and ']' ascii codes not following each other?

Tags: ascii, extended-ascii

Does anyone know why the design decision of having '[' and ']' or '{' and '}' ASCII key codes being two apart instead of one digit was made? OCD triggered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Evolution of Character Codes

Have a look @ the following article: https://web.archive.org/web/20050305043226/http://www.transbay.net/~enf/ascii/ascii.pdf

I found it from the following stackexchange article: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149901/94281

Ascii was an evolutionary result but was based on previous work/inventions such as telegrams and morse code.

Additionally, there were many different versions and  proposals before we reached a final order and result.

It seems that in some of the initial proposals `[` and `]` had been placed together.

For example:

[image]

However, after the X3.2 meeting, the `\` was added in between:

[image]

This is again visible in a publication from 1962:

[image]

Source: [Source documents on the history of character codes, 1962-06](https://archive.org/details/enf-ascii-1962-06/page/n21/mode/2up)

### Substitution Characters

Reading the archive from [Source Documents on the history of character Codes](https://archive.org/details/enf-ascii-1962-06/page/n21/mode/2up)
page 38 shows that some of the characters were grouped together and were planned to be substituted with other characters in 26 character languages:

[image]

A similar note is made about the characters '< = >' in relation to substituting them for more business-friendly characters.

[image]

**References:**

- [The Evolution of Character Codes, 1874-1968 - Eric Fischer](https://web.archive.org/web/20050305043226/http://www.transbay.net/~enf/ascii/ascii.pdf)
- https://github.com/ericfischer/ascii/blob/master/ascii.ms
- [Source documents on the history of character codes, 1962-06](https://archive.org/details/enf-ascii-1962-06/page/n21/mode/2up)

**Note: Researching this further to see why the X3.2 meeting resulted in this change.**

Comment: Interesting. I observe that `< >` were together in the first two versions you show, first in column 2 then in column 3, and they ended up separated by `=` in column 3.

Comment: This is unbelievable xD Very interesting results thanks!

Comment: ```They decided that a left brace
({), vertical line ( ), and right brace (}) would be
useful and would remain comprehensible when they
were mapped onto the brackets and backslash in
upper-case-only versions of the code. ```